# Can I ensure the order of dialog conversations in sql service broker?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replication, service-broker

So, I've got an 'A' server and a 'B' server.  We are using SQL Service Broker to perform replication.  An application we have will need to write data to either the 'A' server, or the 'B' server.  (one may be down, and the other one should take over)

Data is written to the database only within stored procedures, which are wrapped in a transaction to keep the data in the tables consistent.

One of these transactions will include all of the messages to be sent to the peer server.  So, in my application code, when I attempt to commit a transaction, it should write all of the data to the tables, and send the messages to the peer server.

However, if the peer server is down, then the messages will wait in sys.transmission_queue.

**Message order within a dialog conversation is guaranteed, but can I ensure that dialog conversations will be processed in the order that I created them?**

For example, I could have a problem if the 'B' server is down, A user writes data to the 'A' server.  Once the 'B' server is back up again, if those dialog conversations are processed out of order, they may not work correctly.  (They could try to insert data with a bad foreign key, or something like that).

I am working under the following assumptions:

1. I should have a single dialog
   conversation for each transaction.
2. The form of the solution must be as
   replication by way of sql service
   broker.  (This is done in other
   parts of the database, so any reason
   to use an alternate strategy must be
   compelling).

Comment: Can you point out the most important differences between your custom solution and database mirroring and why you chose not to use the latter?

Comment: It wasn't my choice.  I'm adding functionality to an existing system.  I have some new tables which were created for my part, and some tables that are shared with other sub-systems.  The other sub-systems replicate data to a peer server in a similar fashion, so if a new strategy were to be chosen (like mirroring) then would it be appropriate to have two different replication strategies, or how much would it cost to rewrite code belonging to other projects?  (The latter almost certainlly won't happen.)

Answer (score 0):

You should user Broker Priority.[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934170.asp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934170.aspx)